# How do I created nested JSON object with Python?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, flask

I have the following code:

```
data = {}
data['agentid'] = 'john'
data['eventType'] = 'view'
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

print json_date = {"eventType":"view,"agentid":"john"}

I would like to create a nested JSON object- for example::

```
{
    "agent": { "agentid", "john"} ,
    "content": {
        "eventType": "view",
        "othervar": "new"
    }
}
```

How would I do this?  I am using Python 2.7.

Cheers
Nick

Comment: probably what you are looking for is simply assignment like `data = {
    "agent": { "agentid", "john"} ,
    "content": {
        "eventType": "view",
        "othervar": "new"
    }
}`

Comment: I would like to maintain the format I currently have of setting each key/value pair first. Is that possible? Cheers

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could nest the dictionaries as follows:

```
jsondata = {}
agent={}
content={}
agent['agentid'] = 'john'
content['eventType'] = 'view'
content['othervar'] = "new"

jsondata['agent'] = agent
jsondata['content'] = content
print(json.dumps(jsondata))
```

Output:

> print {"content": {"eventType": "view", "othervar": "new"}, "agent":
>   {"agentid": "john"}}

Comment: for pretty print: print(json.dumps(jsondata, indent=4))